# obiee12c RCU creation fails with oracle database 19c

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have installed OBIEE12c(12.2.1.4). OBIEE12c certification matrix says RCU creation utility supports oracle database 19c. However, when I run RCU creation utility it fail prerequisite with the following message

```
Processing command line ....
Repository Creation Utility - Checking Prerequisites
Checking Global Prerequisites
The selected database is more recent than the supported list of certified databases for this version of Oracle Fusion Middleware. For the most recent list of certified databases, refer to the Supported System Configurations information on the Oracle Technology Network.
```

Please anyone help me what should I do to creation meta data repository using RCU with oracle database 19c.

Comment: You need to contact your Oracle support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the global prereq check by setting environment variable to run RCU with oracle database19c.

First, run the following command to skip the global prereq check.
export RCU_SKIP_PRE_REQS=GLOBAL
Then, re-run RCU in silent mode